# Why When we look a white source of light from close it appears white but from far it appear bluish?

Tags: visible-light, scattering

When we have a good amount of intensity light source and when we turn it  ON

When looking from **close** we see white light beams (glow/scattering) But looking from **far** it look bluish.

Why?

Comment: Could you give an example please of when it looks bluish.  The sun appears redder at sunrise or sunset, when the light to our eyes is passing through more of the earth's atmosphere, so perhaps the blue is absorbed/scattered

Comment: Where have you observed such phenomenon?

Comment: @space guy, When we open torch , we see white light , but not blue people say because white is scattered more and blue at negligible amount. But than why sky is blue, if more intensity light is coming than it may scatter more blue colour but. ......white scattering will also be more proportionally, than why sky appear blue not white?

Comment: @PM 2Ring, I mean when we turn 'on' or switch on the torch

Comment: In most dialects of English, we don't use the phrase "open the torch" to mean "turn on the torch". When I open a torch, I see batteries.

Comment: Also, Americans call that device a flashlight. In American English, a torch is powered by fire https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torch

Comment: @PM 2Ring sorry! For confusion

Comment: "people say" usually means that the statement is an unfounded rumor. You should read up on Rayleigh scattering.

Answer (score 0):

The sky is blue and the sunset red because the atmosphere scatters more blue than red. I have never observed a distant white light showing a blue tint.